# Bootstrap Collapsible Form -- Just One Panel Available at a Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the following Bootstrap accordion/collapsible form on my website. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eswv56ha/

Here's my HTML markup too:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="checkout-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default checkout-panel" id="panel-billing">
    <div class="panel-heading checkout-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-billing">
      <h4 class="panel-title checkout-acc-title"> <a class="accordion-checkout" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-billing">Delivery Address <i class="checkout-accordion-icon">&#xe04b;</i></a> </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-billing" class="panel-collapse details collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body checkout-inside">
            Content First

        <button id="toggle-delivery" type="button" class="btn-checkout" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-delivery">Deliver to This Address</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default checkout-panel" id="panel-shipping">
    <div class="panel-heading checkout-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-delivery">
      <h4 class="panel-title checkout-acc-title"> <a class="accordion-checkout collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-delivery">Delivery Options <i class="checkout-accordion-icon">&#xe04b;</i></a> </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-delivery" class="panel-collapse details collapse">
      <div class="panel-body checkout-inside">
        Content Second
        <button id="toggle-payment" type="button" class="btn-checkout" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-payment">Select Delivery Option</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default checkout-panel" id="panel-payment">
    <div class="panel-heading checkout-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-payment">
      <h4 class="panel-title checkout-acc-title"> <a class="accordion-checkout collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-payment">Payment <i class="checkout-accordion-icon">&#xe04b;</i></a> </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-payment" class="panel-collapse details collapse">
      <div class="panel-body checkout-inside">
        Content Third
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div>

</div>
```

I used dummy content for the panel body as the content is generated dynamically with PHP. The accordion replaces the checkout form on my WooCommerce website. So far, it is fully functional and behaves as expected, however, I'd like to go one step further and somehow disable the second and third panels (Delivery Options & Payment) when the first one (Delivery Address) is toggled. Then, when the user clicks "Deliver to This Address" button, the second panel would be enabled. At this point, the first panel (Delivery Address) will be collapsed BUT still enabled/toggleable, the second one (Delivery Options) will be toggled, and the third one (Payment) should be disabled/not toggleable. When the user clicks "Select Delivery Option," the last/third panel (Payment) should be enabled. The first (Delivery Address) and second (Delivery Options) panels should be collapsed BUT active, and the third one (Payment) should be enabled and toggled.

Once the third panel is toggled/activated/enabled, the rest would be collapsed, but still accessible - i.e. if the user wants to go back to her billing info and change the address or select a different delivery option.

Ideally, I'd like to apply an overlay to the disabled panels, like this: 
[image]

As they become enabled/active, the overlay would be gradually removed. How can I do this?

Comment: Please note that you have duplicate code in your HTML. Namely, the `data-*` and `href` attributes are both on `panel-heading` and `panel-title`. Also, consistency wise you have a panel named  `panel-shipping` which its collapsable content named `collapse-delivery`.

Comment: @Cooleronie Yes, I know I have the `data-` and `href` attributes on both the `panel-heading` and `panel-title`. I wanted the entire heading to be clickable, otherwise it will make customer experience rather bad. They should be able to toggle the accordion panels by clicking anywhere on the heading, not just on the `panel-title`. Thanks!

Comment: Then just remove the ones in `panel-title` and the anchor along with it.

Comment: @Cooleronie Just did and it's working well. Thanks! But now my arrows aren't because the collapsed class isn't appended to the panel-heading of panels #2 and #3 when the panels are toggled. The same thing is happening with your Plunker as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Javascript to accomplish this. To begin, look at [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods) for the events that fire if a collapsible element is toggled. For example:

```
//Fires when #panel-delivery is triggered to be shown
$('#panel-delivery').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
       // Enable / Disable other panels here. 
    })
```

[And this will work just fine as you can see here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dmDkOfp3VJfeQMctR7k0?p=preview). Do note I altered some of your code, since your markup is all over the place. I put the Jquery on the bottom of `<body>` so it's easier to see what it does.

My advice would be to first validate whatever the user needs to fill in before he can press the button to access the next panel. Could be as simple as making sure no required input is empty. (Not as a replacement for any back-end validating, but solely for better user experience).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Validating data is definitely a good point, still, as I'm quite new to all things PHP/Javascript, I'm not really sure how to do it. It would most likely need to be done via AJAX so the page doesn't refresh when the user clicks the button and the form is being validated. Plus it helps with user experience.

Comment: The code seems to be working, but now my arrows aren't because the `collapsed` class isn't appended to the `panel-heading` of panels #2 and #3 when the panels are toggled. The same thing is happening with your Plunker as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexP. In the Plunker I removed the arrows since they served no purpose for the example, as well everything inside the `<a>` tag. If you can deliver a Plunker (or any other similar tool) with your HTML+CSS (and JS if any) with working arrows I'll look into it for you.

Comment: @AlexP. [You can do some validation with Jquery](https://plnkr.co/edit/mvJuryqlKqm0XnPw4ECU?p=preview). Or simply google "javascript input validation", there are tons of small add-ons that only require you to add a few classes to each input. Even [HTML5](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/) has options to make an input required (within a form). Once the form is send, you can validate it again in the back-end, given that one can bypass the javascript.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vjcoLxh/ I'm not sure how to import the ionicons font, so I've left that out. However, the `transform: rotate(0deg);` issue will be visible anyway.

Comment: I have used this fiddle as inspiration to validate the form and it seems to be working well: http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/ For the arrows: https://jsfiddle.net/9vjcoLxh/ I'm not sure how to import the ionicons font, so I've left that out. However, the transform: rotate(0deg); issue will be visible anyway.

Comment: For the arrows, simply add `removeClass('collapsed')` after the `href` attribute is set. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vjcoLxh/2/). Also please note that once you start changing a lot of css based on an element's state it's more manageable to add/remove classes for css styling, so you can have all css in your stylesheet and the JS files free from CSS. (so have a class in your stylesheet named `*.disabled` and add that class to the element once it's disabled)

Comment: Weird. It's working in your fiddle, but not on my end. The class is removed once the panel becomes active/enabled, but not toggled back if I collapse it/toggle it. Here's the snippet I used: https://jsfiddle.net/ct3gxepq/ I haven't touched the CSS so far.

Comment: LAST UPDATE: I found the issue. It was the bootstrap.min.js version I enqueued (3.3.4). I changed it to 3.0.0 and it's working perfectly. Is there any particular issue that my occur if I'm not using the last version of bootstrap.min.js? Just marked your answer as the solution by the way, thanks a bunch!